# QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged issues

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsItem and I just want to detect when the position of the object is changed.

I have this function:

```
QVariant ObjectGraphicsItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const 
                                        QVariant &value) {
   if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedHasChanged) {
      //do something
   }
   if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged ) { 
      //here is the issue   
   }
      return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

My problem is that the following condition

```
change == QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged
```

is meet also when I change the size of the object.
What I need is something like below:

```
if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged ) { 
   objectPositionChanged();
}
if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSizeHasChanged ) { 
   objectSizeChanged();
}
```

but QT does not have **QGraphicsItem::ItemSizeHasChanged**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How are you changing the size?

Comment: I have two QDoubleSpinBox, one for height and one for weight. When the user updates the value in these two I will update the size in the model and also in the Scene.

Comment: you could show the code of that, for me it is that apart from changing the size you are changing the position without realizing it.

Comment: You were right , I was changing also the position. I found a fix for my issue. Thanks!